# Display the 0 in PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, select

I'm trying Display the number of satellites per planet. Satellites with a radius of less than 500 km must be ignored and their matching planets must be displayed with a null number. Sort by number of satellites then by planet name.

```
SELECT planet.name, COUNT(CASE WHEN satellite.radius > 500
                        THEN 1 END) AS "number of satellites"
FROM planet
JOIN satellite
        ON (satellite.id_planet = planet.id)
GROUP BY planet.name
ORDER BY "number of satellites", planet.name;
```

When I do that I got

```
  name   | number of satellites
---------+----------------------
 Earth   |                    1
 Neptune |                    1
 Jupiter |                    4
 Uranus  |                    4
 Saturn  |                    5
```

But I'm supposed to have this :

```
 planet  | number of satellites
---------+----------------------
 Mars    |                    0
 Mercury |                    0
 Venus   |                    0
 Earth   |                    1
 Neptune |                    1
 Jupiter |                    4
 Uranus  |                    4
 Saturn  |                    5
```

I don't understand why the Zero are not present

Comment: you should provide more information like table descriptions, buts seems to be that as you are doing a join with satellites, planet without satellites won't be listed.

Comment: You're inner joining so do you actually have rows for planets with satellites < 500km? Try a *left join*; also what is a *null number*?

Comment: 1) 0 != NULL. NULL is unknown so it has no value 2) `CASE WHEN satellite.radius > 500 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END`?

Comment: Your right ! I just add a left join and it works but im' not sure that I understand why :/

Comment: [sql-outer-joins](https://mode.com/sql-tutorial/sql-outer-joins/)